# Create Bar chart in Power BI as the attahced sample

Tags: powerbi, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-custom-visuals

I need to create the attached graph type with the sample data set attached. Need your super power to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Mock data and Graph type]

Answer (score 0):

The exact chart will not be possible in Power BI. You can create a stacked column chart with a line. use min for the lower column, range for the upper column in the stack. Format the lower column white, so it is invisible. Use allocation as the line data and format the line to show no line and only markers. You won't be able to make the marker a dash in Power BI.

[image]